# Synchronus get character in Node.js

Tags: node.js, synchronization

I want to get one character at a time synchronously from the terminal and read it in as soon as a key is pressed. I am having troubles getting it working on windows and it should work like getc() in C/C++.

console.log("Other code!");

x = getCharcter(); //not sure how to do this synchronously

process.out.write(x);

console.log("More code!");

Comment: Try [robotjs](https://github.com/octalmage/robotjs), it can detect key presses.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
const readline = require('readline');

readline.emitKeypressEvents(process.stdin);
process.stdin.setRawMode(true);

process.stdout.write("press character: ")

process.stdin.on('keypress', (str, key) => {
  process.stdout.write("[pressed " + key.name + "] ")
  if (key.ctrl && key.name == 'c') process.exit();
})
```

Comment: This is still an asynchronous call. The on key press starts a new thread.